# Is it possible to Configure NUnit test runner to exclude .NET Core projects?

Tags: c#, devops, nunit, teamcity

I am in the process of migrating projects from *.NET Framework* to *.NET Core*. We have several hundred of them with lots of unit tests that are executed by the NUnit console runner. Recently, we discovered that the *.NET Framework* version of the NUnit console runner tries to execute the .NET Core tests as well and fails at this task. The test .dlls are built to the same output folder for DevOps purposes.

As a workaround we started to specifically exclude the projects that we already migrated to .NET Core and run them separately with `dotnet test`.

This is fine with a couple of projects but it is going to get very messy very soon so I am looking for a way to solve this.
I know there is a way to exclude certain categories and we could mark the `TestFixtures` in the migrated projects with some category but I would like to know if there is a better way around this.

**Is it possible to Configure NUnit test runner to check for the target framework and exclude .NET Core projects?**

Comment: FWIW, most folks have no problem running a mix of .NET Framework and .NET Core tests using NUnit. But to get an answer, you need to be more specific.By "NUnit test runner", you might mean a number of different things, like nunit-console.exe, nunit vs test adapter, nunitlite runner, etc. Also, please say what version of whatever it is you are running.

Comment: I'd like to put it the other way around: what about running all your tests (both .NET Framework and "Core") via `dotnet test`?